# How to cite a Table that has been copied from some other resources?

Tags: tables, citing

I've copied a table from internet and I want to cite that table. How can I do it?

Comment: PLease explain better what your problem is. You have the url of the table? In which kind should it be cited?  Please give us an example of the text/result you want to have ...

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to cite that table"? Shouldn't you be citing the publication that contains the table?

Comment: You haven't told us what sort of document you're writing, or how you cite other materials.   That is more relevant to your question than the software you use.  I'd suggest migrating to academia.SE but we don't know whether this is academic work. (Also note that you *might* be better going back a step to a better source than citing a random table from the internet).  I've been known to use "...based on a table from Reference 16 with data from Reference 17" in a numeric citation style.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\caption[Text for the LOT, if needed]{The text over/under the tabular 
    (\small Copied from \url{http://any.where.org})}
```

LOT: List of Tables

Or create an `online` entry for the bibliography and use:

```
 \caption[Text for the LOT, if needed]{The text over/under the tabular~\cite{xyz}}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is use of package `copyrightbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{copyrightbox} % for copyright

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
\caption[short caption, if needed]{Long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, caption.}
\copyrightbox[b]{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccccccccccccccccc \\
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb & cccccccccccccccccccc \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
                }{source \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289748/}}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If table is copied as image, than instead of table construction use `includegrahics{copied table image}`

[image]